# Complex Query design for access database

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

I have the following three tables (only showing the required fields for representation reasons).

Table 'product_master'

```
ID  ProductName
1   Jens
2   T-shirt
3   Shirt
4   Cap
```

Table 'bill'

```
ID  Invoiceno   Date
1   INV001       19/9/2013
2   INV002       20/9/2013
3   INV003       20/9/2013
```

Table 'billDetails'

```
ID  Invoiceno   Productid       Qyt
1   INV001             1             2
2   INV001             2             3
3   INV001             4             1
4   INV002             2             1
5   INV002             3             2
6   INV003             1             3
7   INV003             4             2
```

**The output I want**

SalesReport(Daily between any two date)

```
ProductName TotalSales  Date
Jens                2         19/9/2013
T-shirt             4         19/9/2013
Shirt               2         19/9/2013
Cap                 1         19/9/2013
Jens                3         20/9/2013
T-shirt             0         20/9/2013
Shirt               0         20/9/2013
Cap                 2         20/9/2013
```

This query didn't work:

```
        SELECT
        [PM.product_master], [SUM(IM.Qyt)], [BM.Date] FROM
        [product_master] AS PM
        INNER JOIN 
        [billDetails] AS IM
        ON
        [PM.sno] = [IM.prod_sno]
        INNER JOIN
        [bill] AS BM
        ON
        [IM.Invoiceno] = [BM.Invoiceno]
```

Comment: +1 for asking a good question. What is the output of your SELECT?

Comment: it's given syntax error. and other query which i try it given me wrong selection of data

Comment: Please tell us the exact error message...

Comment: This error 'Syntax error (missing operator) in query expersion '

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now i want output like this way SalesReport(Daily between any two
>   date)

In order to compute total sales per day, you will have to `group` the data by date. For specifying period, you will have to use the `having` clause.

```
SELECT product_master.ProductName, Sum(billDetails.Qty) AS SumOfQty, bill.Dated
FROM bill 
INNER JOIN (
product_master INNER JOIN billDetails ON product_master.ID = billDetails.ProductId
) ON bill.InvoiceNo = billDetails.InvoiceNo
GROUP BY product_master.ProductName, bill.Dated
HAVING bill.Dated Between #9/19/2013# And #9/20/2013#
ORDER BY bill.Dated, product_master.ProductName
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
select product_master.ProductName
       ,SUM(billDetails.Qyt) as TotalSales
       ,bill.Date 
from billDetails
inner join bill on billDetails.Invoiceno = bill.Invoiceno 
inner join product_master on product_master.Id = billDetails.Productid
```

Comment: Can you give me our db script !

Comment: database in access how can i give db script  ?

Comment: It's show me the error after this one 'SUM(billDetails.Qyt) as TotalSales'

Comment: @RameshRajendran You probably got tripped up by the `Qyt` typo (instead of `Qty`) in the question. People can be pretty sloppy when posting questions and then we all get frustrated when the answers we provide don't work....